# Cordova add platform wp7 issues

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, command-line-interface

I'm using Cordova 3.4 CLI and i get an error when I add a wp7 platform.
after the command "cordova platform add wp7"

```
C:\quelle\apps\MHI-4Web>cordova platform add wp7
Checking wp7 requirements...
Error: Requirements check failed: Eingabefehler: F?r die Dateierweiterung ".js" gibt es kein Skriptmodul.

    at C:\Users\msp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\metadata\wp7_parser.js:60:22
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:651:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:966:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
```

I'm using Windows phone 7.1 sdk on Windows 7 x64 os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Win7 make a .reg file with following content

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js]
@="JSFile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js\PersistentHandler]
@="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.js]
```

then you have to rightclick on a .js file, Open with.., and select editor of your choice and dont forget the tick on always use this